# Not able to find javapasswordsdk.PSDKPasswordRequest maven dependency

Tags: java, maven

I am working on migrating one project to maven. I can see 2 import statements in legacy code like:

import javapasswordsdk.PSDKPasswordRequest;
import javapasswordsdk.exceptions.PSDKException;

I dont see any maven dependency available in maven central for these imports to add in my pom.xml.
Can anybody help me to get this jar ?

Answer (score 1):

The classes mentioned are part of a commercial offering called cyberark. 
See the following [Cyberark Enterprise vault product page](https://www.cyberark.com/products/privileged-account-security-solution/enterprise-password-vault/)

This library won't be up on maven central.

If an internal maven repo exists it may be there. Otherwise, this library is often packaged with application using the provided scope

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.cyberark</groupId>
      <artifactId>JavaPasswordSDK</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
```